# Consuming PowerShell module from private DevOps feed fails

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, nuget

I have followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops and provisioned a PowerShell module, MyModule, in a Azure DevOps feed.

I have setup my local machine with a PAT token and a private, trusted PSRepository called MyRepo.

When I run `Find-Module -Name MyModule -Repository MyRepo`, it finds MyModule, but if I pipe that into `Install-Module` i get the following error:

```
Install-Package: Cannot find the path 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\355836562\MyModule.0.0.2\MyModule.psd1' because it does not exist.
```

Verbose output from the Install-Module command:

```
VERBOSE: Downloading module 'MyModule' with version '0.0.2' from the repository 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_packaging/MyModule/nuget/v2'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_packaging/MyModule/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='MyModule'' for ''.
VERBOSE: InstallPackage' - name='MyModule', version='0.0.2',destination='C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\1414719836'
VERBOSE: DownloadPackage' - name='MyModule', version='0.0.2',destination='C:\Users\Ax\AppData\Local\Temp\1414719836\MyModule.0.0.2\MyModule.0.0.2.nupkg', uri='https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_packaging/MyModule/nuget/v2?id=mymodule&version=0.0.2'
VERBOSE: Downloading 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_packaging/MyModule/nuget/v2?id=mymodule&version=0.0.2'.
VERBOSE: Completed downloading 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_packaging/MyModule/nuget/v2?id=mymodule&version=0.0.2'.
VERBOSE: Completed downloading 'MyModule'.
VERBOSE: Hash not found for the package 'MyModule'.
VERBOSE: InstallPackageLocal' - name='MyModule', version='0.0.2',destination='C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\1414719836'
VERBOSE: Validating the 'MyModule' module contents under 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\1414719836\MyModule.0.0.2' path.
Install-Package: Cannot find the path 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\1414719836\MyModule.0.0.2\MyModule.psd1' because it does not exist.
```

I can publish the same module to the PowerShell Gallery and load it just fine from there.

I think it might be something with the version number in the folder name, but for now I am pretty clueless.

Has anyone stumbled opun a similar issue?

Config:

```
PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.7
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.7
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

PS> Get-Module powershellget -ListAvailable

    Directory: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Script     2.2.5                 PowerShellGet                       Desk      {Find-Command, Find-DSCResource, Find-M…
```

Comment: When running the command, a tmp file gets created in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp` - I assume that is a temp file for the data stream. But it never gets turned into the expected nupkg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is no longer supported. Changing to PSResourceGet as described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/psresourceget-preview-is-now-available/ solved my issue.